# When using De Morgan's Law, does the negation go before or after the quantifier?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, quantifiers

For example, I want to use De Morgan's law on the following equation: $\forall x (P(x) \wedge R(x))$. Would it be number 1. $\neg \forall x(\neg P(x) \vee \neg R(x))$, or would it be number 2. $\forall x \neg(\neg P(x) \vee \neg R(x))$? 
I need to know which way is correct to complete one of my proofs, thanks.

Comment: Take option 2 please

Comment: See [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Extension_to_predicate_and_modal_logic): $∀x \ (P(x) \land  R(x)) \equiv \lnot ∃x \  (\lnot P(x) \lor \lnot R(x))$.

Comment: So in the case that ∀x~(~R(x) Λ ~P(x)), would it be legal to distribute the ∀x as follows: ~(∀x(~R(x)) Λ ∀x(~P(x)))?

Comment: NO; use De Morgan to "move inside" negations when they are in front of a formula with  $\land$ and $\lor$; use equivalence between $\forall x \lnot$ and $\lnot \exists x$ and the corresponding ones to "move inside" the negation when quantifiers are present; use distribution of quantifiers when the quantifiers are in front of a formula with $\land$ and $\lor$.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback and advice. I know you told me to reference my textbook, but I assure you I already have. My main issue with figuring this stuff out is the fact that I have to convert everything in the equation to negatives to use De Morgan's law. So, I got confused as to where the negations went. Thank you.

Comment: Also, I am attempting to distribute the universal quantifier to every predicate symbol since that's what my professor asked me to do. So, that is why I was trying to hard to make the OR into and AND so that I could distribute the universal quantifier.

Comment: In the end, if we have $∀x¬(¬R(x)∧¬P(x))$ we can rewrite it (using De Morgan) into $∀x(R(x)∨P(x))$. But now, we cannot distribute $\forall$ over $\lor$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can distribute $\forall$ over $\land$ to get:

> $∀x (P(x) ∧ R(x)) ≡ (∀x \ P(x) ∧ ∀x \ R(x))$.

We can get the same result in a more convoluted way using De Morgan.

We have to start with the equivalence:

> $∀x \ (P(x) ∧ R(x)) ≡ ¬∃x¬ \ (P(x) ∧ R(x))$,

then use De Morgan to "move inside" the inner negation sign to get:

> $¬∃x¬ \ (P(x) ∧ R(x)) ≡ ¬∃x \ (¬P(x) ∨ ¬R(x))$,

then distribute $\exists$ over $\lor$ to get:

> $¬∃x \ (¬P(x) ∨ ¬R(x)) ≡ ¬(∃x¬ P(x) ∨ ∃x¬ R(x))$.

Finally, a further application of De Morgan will produce:

> $¬∃x¬ P(x) ∧ ¬∃x¬ R(x)$.